# Best / simplest way to transfer data from one Oracle database to another

Tags: java, rest, oracle11g, etl, jboss5.x

I need to develop an app  that will pull data from Oracle database A (via a view sitting on A) and put that data into database B. The app will then expose the data in Database B via a rest API. So far the only technical restrictions are that this app has to run in JBOSS 5 App Server. I'm just wondering what the cleanest implementation should be. Should the transfer between DBs occur at the DB rather than app level? Any advice would be appreciated. The data size is minimal... 9-10 columns and about 1800 rows.

Comment: You can perhaps ask this question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/
SO is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks for that; I'll probably do that. I think the reason I initially thought to post the question here is because we initially envisioned the transfer as something that would happen at the application programming level and it's only after marinating on the idea that I thought maybe it made sense more on the DB level.

Comment: Usually, you export data from a database and import data into a different database.  [Oracle Import Export FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

- There are bellow ways to do this.

  1. import export if you can manage to call import export api from you program.
  2. you can use materialized view by setting up db link.
  3. you can use third party tool like informatica.